# Views in laravel are not updated after adding git

Tags: php, git, laravel, caching

I added git system to my laravel project and I after editing some files I realised that the changes in the views are not displayed. I tried to clear view cache and the cache of laravel but nothing works. Even when I delete the content of the view it is still displayed. I opened storage/views folder and there were no cached files which is strange, because I made a copy of the project without git and everything works fine.

Comment: Are you referring that local changes are not reflected?

Comment: Yes, I am editing the file on my local machine and when I refresh the page the view remains the same.

Comment: File remains the same or contents in browser remains the same?

Comment: The contents in browser.

Comment: I think you are editing the wrong file .

Comment: I checked it several times and I even cloned the whole remote repository, ran composer install and served the application. I tried to change 5 files but no changes are displayed.

Comment: Try commenting out any one of the routes and check if route is accessible

Comment: Yes it is still accessible, i commented out two different routes. I definitely know that it is related to git system. Somehow it only the old files are used. I even changed the controller`s code but no result.

Comment: 'php artisan view:clear'  already tried or not ??

Comment: Yes I tried to clear both cache and view. But nothing works.

Comment: Seems like any change in a file is discarded by git.

Comment: By the way, when I push changes to remote repository everything works fine.

Comment: The problem was with cipher key and .env file that has not been pushed to the server by git. PROBLEM IS SOLVED.